# Convert all T values using LINQ and assign them to an array of different type

Tags: c#, linq, generics, casting

I wish to be able to modify some parameter value of generic type T, and I am trying to do this with LINQ, but I cannot figure it out.
Here is what I have:

```
public static T ConvertParam(T param)
{    
    T val = param.Select(i => { i = (T)ModifyValue(Convert.ToDouble(i)); });

    return val;
}

public static UInt64 ModifyValue(double value)
{
    UInt64 result = (UInt64)(value) * 3 + 1;

    return result;
}
```

In this case the problem resides in the value returned by "ModifyValue()" that needs to be cast to whatever T param contains, but I am not sure how to do that. T can be an int, uint, int[], uint[], etc.
Handling the arrays is also tricky.

I have also tried with a normal for loop as here below:

```
public static T ConvertParam(T param)
{
    List<UInt64> output = new List<UInt64>();

    foreach (var v in param)
    {
        output.Add(ModifyValue(Convert.ToDouble(v));
    }

    return output.ToArray();
}
```

The problem here again is that the returned value may or may not be an array. It should just return the modified version of T param.

### EDIT

Note that ModifyValue() is just a dummy example. "param" MUST be generic!

### EDIT 2

Maybe I could do something around these lines (not sure how to though):

```
public static T ConvertParam(T param)
{
    T ret = param.ToList().ConvertAll(i => i = new T() { ModifyValue(Convert.ToDouble(i)) });

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `ConvertParam` should have generic type argument `T`, otherwise ist declaration is invalid

Comment: So based on what the `ModifyValue` is doing, is your `value` always a `double`?

Comment: How do you intend on calling `ConvertParam`? Why do you think it should be generic?

Comment: Why are you converting input to double only to cast it to `UInt64` ?

Comment: Why you use arrays explicitly? IEnumerable<T> should be more suitable.

Comment: @devcrp, yes it is

Comment: @stackMeUp if your value is always a double why do you need generics?

Comment: @stackMeUp Please, answer the next questions to clarify the problem. **1.** Do you want to convert `T param` to `List<UInt64>` if `T` is a collection of items? **2.** If `T` is a single value do you wan to convert it to a single value (not `List` or `Array`) of type `UInt64`?

Comment: @Sweeper, param has to be generic as it is part of a class a class that can contain different type of param (ie. int, uint, bool, int[], etc.)

Comment: @GuruStron, this is just a dumb example. There are many functions/libraries doing all sorts of things with param.

Comment: @Stejin, Any example to suggest?

Comment: @Marco Salerno, the problem is not about ModifyValue(), it is about using a T param. ModifyValue() could be anything. It is just a dummy example of what a library function could be.

Comment: I think your exaple is not clear enough, it really depends on what the `ModifyValue()` should do to modify the value. You cannot modify a value if you don't know its type before, it should at least derive from the same interface or base class. It's hard to give you an answer :)

Comment: @stackMeUp so here is your solution, you can't use generics. You must use overloading and specify every possible interaction.

Comment: @devcrp, ModifyValue() is not what matters here. It takes a double as input, that's all! But param must be of type T. That is the requirement here. The context does not matter.

Comment: @Marco Salerno, thanks. Are you saying that I should overload "ConvertParam(T param)" for all possible param types?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look to me like that would actually compile.

I think you have two vital things missing first as Pavel suggested in his comment you are returning T from ConvertParam and it takes and argument of T, but you haven't declared T.

Secondly, you are using LINQ against a generic type, but there is nothinh that allows the compiler to know that param is queryable by LINQ.  I think you need to change your code to something like this

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> ConvertParam<T>(IEnumerable<T> param)
{
    // This seems redundant
    // List<UInt64> output = new List<UInt64>(); 

    var val = param.Select(i => (T)ModifyValue(Convert.ToDouble(i)));

    return val;
}

public static UInt64 ModifyValue(double value)
{
    UInt64 result = (UInt64)(value) * 3 + 1;

    return result;
}
```

EDIT: As others have said I'm not sure your code makes sense from a use case point of view.

Comment: I was about to write more or less the same. ;)

Comment: Thanks, that does work either. Maybe my use of "Select" is incorrect?

Comment: Just noticed your Select is indeed incorrect, you are assigning something new to i but not returning it.  Have updated answer